# Discord button interaction lets everyone interact with it

Tags: javascript, discord.js, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to code a tic tac toe command for my Discord bot, and I want that only the creator of the interaction and the tagged user can play, so that everyone else doesn't interrupt it, I tried by making a filter like so:

```
const taggedUser = interaction.options.get("user").id;
        const filter = (ButtonInteraction) => {

            if (ButtonInteraction.user.id === interaction.user.id ||
                ButtonInteraction.user.id === taggedUser) return true;

            else return interaction.followUp({content: `${ButtonInteraction.user} this is not your match! >:(`, ephemeral: true});
        }
```

but when the command gets executed, and neither the interaction author or the tagged user tries to interact, the interaction is successful, and I recieve the message in ephemeral form, what can I do? (also suggestion for coding the tictactoe command are appreciated :3). Here's the full code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("tictactoe")
    .setDescription("Play a game of tic tac toe with your friends!")
    .addUserOption(option =>
        option.setName("user")
        .setDescription("The user you wanna play with.")
        .setRequired(true)),

    async execute(client, interaction, Discord) {

        await interaction.deferReply();

        const taggedUser = interaction.options.get("user").id;

        let grid = [
            new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents([
                new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("1").setLabel(" ").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
                new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("2").setLabel(" ").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
                new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("3").setLabel(" ").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
            ]),

            new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents([
                new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("4").setLabel(" ").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
                new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("5").setLabel(" ").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
                new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("6").setLabel(" ").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
            ]),

            new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents([
                new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("7").setLabel(" ").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
                new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("8").setLabel(" ").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
                new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("9").setLabel(" ").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
            ])
        ];

        await interaction.editReply({content: `Your turn, ${interaction.user}! (X)`, components: grid});

        const filter = (ButtonInteraction) => {

            if (ButtonInteraction.user.id === interaction.user.id ||
                ButtonInteraction.user.id === taggedUser) return true;

            else return interaction.followUp({content: `${ButtonInteraction.user} this is not your match! >:(`, ephemeral: true});

        }

        let collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, max: 9 });

        collector.on("collect", async interaction => {

            switch (interaction.customId) {

                case "1":
                    let row = grid[0].components[0];

                    if (interaction.user.id === taggedUser) row.label = "O";

                    else row.label = "X";

                    row.disabled = true
                    await interaction.update({components: grid})

                    break;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to to this:

```
const filter = ({ user }) => { [...]
```

and **remove** "ButtonInteraction" from the if statements inside the filter.
Let me know if it worked, or i will remove this answer!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately, I tried it, and still gives the same: a third user tries to interact, a X appears and the bot sends to me, and not to that user: ```interaction.followUp({content: `${user} this is not your match! >:(`, ephemeral: true});```. Appreciate your help tho! No need to remove the answer.